NoClassDefFoundError - Adding jar to classpath not working
I'm adding a jar (org.json.simple) to a plugin.
I've looked around for how to do so and everything I see says "Right-click project -> Build Path -> configure -> libraries -> Add External Jar". I even tried "Add Jar" and had the jar in either the root of the project and a lib(s) folder (plugin/jar or plugin/lib/jar). This is not working. When launching the app from eclipse, I keep getting the same error (NoClassDefFoundError). This error occurs if I launch the exported app as well plus splash image doesn't show (separate issue). My current solution is creating a plugin from the jar source and adding that to my feature.
!SESSION 2024-09-01 13:58:16.796 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=unknown
java.version=1.8.0_421
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -product tcmagic.ui.product -clearPersistedState
Command-line arguments:  -product tcmagic.ui.product -data C:\Users\Danny\Downloads\EclipseRcpPluginDev\Neon3\workspace11/../runtime-tcmagic.product -dev file:C:/Users/Danny/Downloads/EclipseRcpPluginDev/Neon3/workspace11/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.pde.core/tcmagic.product/dev.properties -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -consoleLog -clearPersistedState -data @noDefault

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2024-09-01 13:58:20.829
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
org.eclipse.e4.core.di.InjectionException: org.eclipse.swt.SWTException: Failed to execute runnable (java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/json/simple/parser/ParseException)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:65)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.invokeUsingClass(InjectorImpl.java:282)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.invoke(InjectorImpl.java:259)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.invoke(ContextInjectionFactory.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application.lambda$0(E4Application.java:238)
    at java.util.Optional.ifPresent(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application.createE4Workbench(E4Application.java:234)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application.start(E4Application.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:388)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:243)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:673)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:610)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1519)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1492)
Caused by: org.eclipse.swt.SWTException: Failed to execute runnable (java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/json/simple/parser/ParseException)
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4533)
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4448)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:185)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:4211)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3827)
    at tcmagic.ui.Splash.prompt(Splash.java:119)
    at tcmagic.ui.LifeCycle.postContextCreate(LifeCycle.java:25)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:55)
    ... 20 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/json/simple/parser/ParseException
    at tcmagic.db.mtgjson.Mtgjson.getSetListFile(Mtgjson.java:102)
    at tcmagic.db.mtgjson.Mtgjson.getSetLists(Mtgjson.java:110)
    at tcmagic.db.Database.createCards(Database.java:41)
    at tcmagic.ui.Splash.run(Splash.java:51)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:35)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:182)
    ... 29 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.json.simple.parser.ParseException cannot be found by tcmagic.db_1.0.0.qualifier
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:461)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:372)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:364)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:161)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 35 more
An error has occurred. See the log file
C:\Users\Danny\Downloads\EclipseRcpPluginDev\Neon3\workspace11\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.pde.core\tcmagic.product\1725217097207.log.

How do I add a jar to a plugin classpath?

Dependencies for plug-ins are managed entirely by the MANIFEST.MF file at runtime. Tinkering with the Java Build Path directly only affects compile-time. Open the MANIFEST.MF in its proper editor and you'll be able to add the jar there.

Thank you. I was in the middle of trying to answer this when you did. Unfortunately, I can't post answers. I found classpath in the runtime tab and was able to add the jar there. This did not update the build tab but did update the build.properties tab and the build configuration. I also had to add  . to the classpath because it wasn't there for some reason. As for the "separate issue", I just forgot to check the splash and icons folders under binary build.
